# Problem with enumerate package in beamer class

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate

I use this in my personal `.sty` file to change the standard enumerate scheme (when I do homework it better matches the numbering scheme in texts/MSWord):

```
\usepackage{enumerate}

% Change enumerate numbering scheme
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\alph{enumi})} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi} 
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{{(}\roman{enumii}{)}} 
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}
```

But the other day I created a beamer presentation (that didn't call the enumerate package) and I keep getting these errors:

```
/etc/texmf/tex/latex/herron.sty|7 error| \labelenumi undefined.
/etc/texmf/tex/latex/herron.sty|9 error| \labelenumii undefined.
```

It compiles just fine and I have no complaints with the `.pdf` it generates, but I would like to understand why this happens (and make the error go away, mainly because I'm using Vim anf vimlatexsuite and it's a bit of pain to deal with the panes that split out).

Thanks!

Comment: @aditya -- Good call. At first I thought it might be a Vim problem, but now I know it's not. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the beamer class doesn't define `\labelenumi` etc., then `\renewcommand` complains, but nevertheless defines the command so that there is effectively no difference. One possible solution is to use the TeX primitive `\def`, which creates or overwrites commands without checks:

```
\def\labelenumi{\theenumi}
```

Comment: You're right. The problem is that in `enumerate` I can't define the labels like I am. It isn't causing a problem in the end b/c I am not using the `enumerate` package (if I were, the new enumeration wouldn't come across).

Comment: Your pointer led me to this: http://old.nabble.com/beamer-and-labelenumi-td16034658.html I also found a slide deck form a TUG that mentions that `enumerate` label changing doesn't work in beamer class.

Answer (score 17):

With the beamer class, `enumerate` labels can be customized in the desired way:

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\alph{enumi})}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{(\roman{enumii})}
```

[image]