# Using lower-case roman numerals in enumerate lists

Tags: lists, enumerate

when I use

```
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\item 
...
```

I get

```
I
II
```

how I can get

```
i
ii
```

?

I try with

```
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
```

in the begin of file, but not fix the problem.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342498/problem-with-enumeration-using-greek-letters, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201455/enumerate-list-with-greek-letters

Answer (score 208):

There are a number of ways. Here's using the [`enumerate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[i]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's another method via the [`enumitem` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). It yields the same output as above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And then, without any packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\Roman{enumi}}%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\roman{enumi}}%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also the `paralist` package, that works just like `enumerate` in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, with `paralist` the 8th item is misaligned (with `enumerate` it's correct).

Comment: Side note, enumitem is recommended [What's the difference between the enumerate and enumitem packages? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519981/whats-the-difference-between-the-enumerate-and-enumitem-packages) (although it's listed later)

Answer (score 29):

If you want to type:

> I.
>
> II.
>
> III.

Use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[I.]
  \item my text
  \item my text
  \item my text
\end{enumerate}
```

Another possibility for `[I.]` is `[(I)]`, which gives:

> (I)
>
> (II)
>
> (III)

Comment: The question is how to have lowercase roman numeral, not to add a period/dot after the Roman numeral.

Comment: but this was useful information, so thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this package adds the side-effect of changing the indentation for the items - is there any way to avoid this change?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev You might want to check out `enumitem` package (with package option `shortlabels`. It's more customizable than `enumerate`.

Answer (score 10):

For those using **Spanish** with `babel` package, the `enumerate` option `\begin{enumerate}[i]` does not work. To make it work, load the `babel` package with this option:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-lcroman]{babel}
```

**Explanation**:

Spanish babel forces the use of upper case. As the [manual](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf) states:

> Traditional Spanish typography discourages the use of lowercase Roman
> numerals.

The manual justifies this choice referencing the book *José Martínez de Sousa, Diccionario de tipografía y del libro, Madrid, Paraninfo, 3.a ed., 1992.*

Comment: Thanks @luchonacho it's helpful

Comment: Wow, that was a hard one to figure out for me, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the beamer class, try something like:

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\roman{enumi})}
```

or

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{(\roman{enumii})}
```

See: [Problem with enumerate package in beamer class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/problem-with-enumerate-package-in-beamer-class)

Comment: Just use [label=(\roman*)]

Comment: @Smaillns, have you tested it? This would require an extension package.

Comment: \usepackage{enumitem}

Comment: Note: you can remove the braket "()", and add what you want, for instance
\begin{enumerate}[label=\roman*]

Comment: if we use [label=\Roman*] we will get letter on Uppercase instead

Comment: This is covered by Werner's answer, while my answer was focused on the beamer class specifically.

Comment: @Smaillns Why asterisk is needed?