# enumerate tag using the alphabet instead of numbers

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

The default behaviour for the `\begin{enumerate}`tag is to sequentially list the items given by `\item` over the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, ...}.

1. Is it possible to change this to the alphabet {a, b, c, d, ...}
2. How about Roman Numerals {i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, ... }
3. How is this done?

Note that I use emacs 24.3. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/how-do-i-change-the-enumerate-list-format-to-use-letters-instead-of-the-defaul?rq=1 help?

Comment: And for roman numerals: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/using-lower-case-roman-numerals-in-enumerate-lists

Comment: Use the `enumerate` package with `\begin{enumerate}[a]` or `\begin{enumerate}[a.]` or `\begin{enumerate}[i)]`

Comment: @Sigur I think one normally recommends `enumitem` over `enumerate`.

Comment: How would you get a `.` or `)` after the alphabet characters or roman numerals? Is there documentation built-in to emacs?

Comment: Nevermind, I tinkered and figured it out!

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus so, you think this question can be closed as a duplicate or do you still have some doubt?

Answer (score 246):

If you use the `enumitem` package, you can *easily* change the style of the counters.

Here is an example using small letters, capital letters, and Roman numbers as counters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item an apple
\item a banana
\item a carrot
\item a durian
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
\item an apple
\item a banana
\item a carrot
\item a durian
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item an apple
\item a banana
\item a carrot
\item a durian
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Which results in:

[image]