# Latex indent with alphabet list

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to achieve this simple list via overleaf.

```
1. xxx
2. xxx
3. xxx
  (a) First line,
  (b) xxxxx
  (c) xxxx
4. xxx
```

And below is my code now, I am new in latex. I stuck here and don't know how to fix the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\title{Computer Security HW1}
\author{Student Name: Chen-I Chang }
\date{09/13 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item an apple
\item a banana
\item a carrot
\item a durian
\end{enumerate}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

The console threw the error.

> something wrong perhaps missing item

Comment: The optional argument in  `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]` is not defined in standard LaTeX.

Comment: I got the same error if I replace it into `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]`, refer to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129951/enumerate-tag-using-the-alphabet-instead-of-numbers

Comment: You need to load `\usepackage{enumitem}`. This is what @Bernard says

Comment: I understand! You can answer that, I will choose it as the answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bernard mentioned, `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]` is not a standard \LaTeX environment.
Optional arguments about the label of enumeration is offered by `enumitem` package.

So this will do the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\title{Computer Security HW1}
\author{Student Name: Chen-I Chang }
\date{09/13 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}
\section{}
\section{}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
\item an apple
\item a banana
\item a carrot
\item a durian
\end{enumerate}
\section{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that loading `enumitem` with the `shortlabels` option  allows for the same syntax as the `enumerate` package, i.e.

```
\begin{enumerate[(a)]
```

Comment: @Bernard Please write an answer as a better in knowledge member because I don't really know so much (and so doesn't know how to write about it). I will delete my answer and read yours to learn something new

Comment: Not at all, keep your answer. I can complete it (it is fine anyway) – just to give as much information  as possible, t and delete my comment, if you want to.

Comment: No, Please keep your comment and add your name in the edit

Comment: @Bernard I am pinging you