# Enumerate list with greek letters

Tags: miktex, enumerate, texmaker, greek

I am new on LaTeX and I have a problem with a sublist with enumerate.

The content is in Greek and the Wizard of TexMaker has automatically added this part of the code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
```

So, everything I write in the editor is in Greek (even if I write it in English, it automatically changes it to Greek).

The problem I have is in the labels of a sublist. The first list has numbers like `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ....`

The sublist has greek letters which is ok but I have two issues here. The labels are like this `α' -> β' -> γ' -> δ' -> ε' -> þ'`

1) Is there any way to remove the apostrophe? I have tried to include before the `\begin{document}` this line `\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}` but it doesn't work.

2) The second problem is the sixth letter. It should be `στ` whereas it is another character.

I use TexMaker 4.3 with MikTex 2.9

**Edit:** Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item 
       \begin{enumerate}
          \item $45 = 45$
          \item $38 > 36$
          \item $ 456 < 465$
          \item $8.765 < 8970$
          \item $90.876 > 86.945$
          \item $345 < 5.690$ 
        \end{enumerate}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2:** File list using `\listfiles'

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
   greek.ldf    2005/03/30 v1.3l Greek support from the babel system
  lgrenc.def    2013/07/16 v0.9 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
  lgrenc.dfu    2013/07/18 1.4.1 UTF-8 support for Greek
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
supp-pdf.mkii
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular, problem 2 is unclear without a MWE.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for that. I have edited my question with a MWE.

Comment: No need to be sorry! `:-)`

Comment: [This picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xihkk.png) shows what I got from your very code. Maybe you need to update your MiKTeX.

Comment: The last label on the sublist is wrong in base of what greek books use. We use `στ` instead of this symbol. However, after googling, I saw that the right one is the one from LaTeX. As for the apostrophe, I have the latest MiKTeX from the official site.

Comment: I guess `στ` is used for lack of `ϛ` (stigma, U+03DB)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342498/problem-with-enumeration-using-greek-letters, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/using-lower-case-roman-numerals-in-enumerate-lists

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/jcommelin/greek_enumerate

Answer (score 4):

If I use

```
\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}
```

I get no apostrophe (properly, number sign) in second level enumerated lists. The symbol for 6 is “stigma” (U+03DB); if you want to output the combination στ instead of ϛ, you can redefine `\textstigma`:

```
\renewcommand{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}
\renewcommand{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}

\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item
       \begin{enumerate}
          \item $45 = 45$
          \item $38 > 36$
          \item $ 456 < 465$
          \item $8.765 < 8970$
          \item $90.876 > 86.945$
          \item $345 < 5.690$
        \end{enumerate}
    \item ...
    \item ...
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here's my file list:

```
 *File List*
  report.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2014/03/24 3.9k The Babel package
   greek.ldf    2014/07/20 v1.9 Greek support for the babel system
  lgrenc.def    2013/12/02 v0.11.2 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
  lgrenc.dfu    2013/07/18 1.4.1 UTF-8 support for Greek
greek-fontenc.def    2013/11/28 v0.11 Common Greek font encoding definitions
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  lgrcmr.fd    2013/09/01 v1.0 Greek European Computer Regular
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

and the `diff` with yours (`>` means my list, `<` means yours):

```
3c3
< inputenc.sty    2014/04/30 v1.2b Input encoding file
---
> inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
8,10c8,11
<    babel.sty    2014/03/24 3.9k The Babel package
<    greek.ldf    2014/07/20 v1.9 Greek support for the babel system
<   lgrenc.def    2013/12/02 v0.11.2 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
---
>    babel.sty    2008/07/08 v3.8m The Babel package
>  bblopts.cfg    2006/07/31 v1.0 MiKTeX 'babel' configuration
>    greek.ldf    2005/03/30 v1.3l Greek support from the babel system
>   lgrenc.def    2013/07/16 v0.9 LGR Greek font encoding definitions
20,21c21,22
< graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
<   keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
---
> graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
>   keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
24c25
< graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
---
> graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
31a33
> geometry.cfg
34,42d35
< pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
< ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
< epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
<   grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
< kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
< kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
< kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
< etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
< epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

It seems you have an outdated distribution, in particular `babel` and `babel-greek`.

Comment: Looks like that neither `\renewcommand{\textdexiakeraia}{}
\renewcommand{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}` works on me. Maybe I miss something here. :(

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris With that exact code?

Comment: Yes. I copy paste your code and it doesn't work. Neither the apostrophe or the label. Maybe it does matter that I have the 64bit MiKTeX?

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` at the top of the document and report what is written at `* File List *` in the `.log` file, adding it to your question?

Comment: I have added it :)

Comment: As I suspected, you have outdated support for Greek.

Comment: Is there any way to update it manual? Because, when I run the quick build for the first time, it asked me to download packages and it should be the latest versions.

Comment: Use the MiKTeX wizard and look in the site for questions regarding this problem. I'm no expert in MiKTeX.