# Problem with enumeration using greek letters

Tags: enumerate, greek

So this is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\let\textdexiakeraia\relax\alph*)]
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \item 4
        \item 5
        \item 6
        \item 7
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The outcome is this:

[image]

That weird symbol in line 6 is probably supposed to be (στ). What I really want as an outcome is this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is a one-off, the easy thing to do would be `\stepcounter{enumi}` before item 6.  But are you looking for a more robust solution?  Also, could you turn your example into something more complete by including everything we'd need to compile?

Comment: I just added the packages

Comment: Perhaps you want to try out [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277124/10995)?

Comment: I want to do it without a loop.

Comment: Given that the standard numbering has a stigma for six (sometimes rendered as “στ”, will your readers interpret ζ like six or seven?

Comment: @egreg What do you mean? It's just like in the picture I attached.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/using-lower-case-roman-numerals-in-enumerate-lists, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201455/enumerate-list-with-greek-letters

Comment: See https://github.com/jcommelin/greek_enumerate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `moreenum` and `[label=(\greek*)]` you should get what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\greek*)]
        \item 1
        \item 2
        \item 3
        \item 4
        \item 5
        \item 6
        \item 7
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool but the package gets capital $\eta$ wrong - should be (uppercase/lowercase) Η/η whereas it gives the capitalization as "E", duplicating $\Eplison$.

Comment: The problem I am facing is the entire document turns into Greek letters!

Comment: The solution from @chandra works just fine but you need to reverse Greek and English to prevent your document having only Greek letters. \usepackage[greek,english]{babel} It looks like LaTeX understands it like "I will first load greek letters and then the English letters. By doing so I will overwrite all the previously loaded letters."

Answer (score 11):

The `\alph` counter style uses the old fashioned Greek alphabetic numbering.

You can define your own `\greekalph` macro:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\greekalph}[1]{\expandafter\@greekalph\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@greekalph}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\or
  \textalpha\or\textbeta\or\textgamma\or\textdelta\or\textepsilon\or
  \textzeta\or\texteta\or\texttheta\or\textiota\or\textkappa\or
  \textlambda\or\textmu\or\textnu\or\textxi\or\textomicron\or\textpi\or
  \textrho\or\textsigma\or\texttau\or\textupsilon\or\textphi\or
  \textchi\or\textpsi\or\textomega\else\@ctrerr\fi
}
\AddEnumerateCounter{\greekalph}{\@greekalph}{\textomega}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\textstigma}{\textsigma\texttau}}% no stigma

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\let\textdexiakeraia\relax\alph*)]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\item 14
\item 15
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\greekalph*)]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 3
\item 4
\item 5
\item 6
\item 7
\item 8
\item 9
\item 10
\item 11
\item 12
\item 13
\item 14
\item 15
\end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't know why but doesn't seem to wok

Comment: @hola Works for me, just checked in a fresh document.