# Using XeLatex and Polyglossia package with Greek as default Language I need to replace in lists the 6th item from Stigma to SigmaTau (στ). How Can I?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, greek

[image]

I need the number of the sixth list element to be (στ)

Comment: See this answer and maybe adapt to your case https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/342531/250119

Comment: @user202729 That's for `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first want to remove the `ʹ` at the end of numbers, then to patch the relevant macros that produces the stigma to do “sigma tau”.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\anw@true}{ʹ}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\gr@num@i}{Ϛ}{στ}{}{}
\patchcmd{\gr@Num@i}{\MakeUppercase{Ϛ}}{ΣΤ}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item A
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item B
  \item C
  \item D
  \item E
  \item F
  \item G
  \item H
  \end{enumerate}
\item B
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*)]
  \item B
  \item C
  \item D
  \item E
  \item F
  \item G
  \item H
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Works just perfect! Thank you egreg! I just need that piece of code! Thank you again!

Comment: How to fix the same way the Capitalized version of the 6th element so the number is (ΣΤ)?

Comment: I just found it! I should use \gr@Num@i  instead of \gr@num@i. Is that correct?

Comment: @MiltosP. I added the code for the uppercase

Comment: Thank you! Again!:-)