# Enumerate "P#number" instead of "#number"

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

About the `\begin{enumerate}` list environment, when I use `item`, instead of having this in my pdf document

1.

2.

3.

4.

I would like to display the following

P1

P2

P3

P4

Where P is a single character. How can I do that please?

Comment: You can follow some of the guidelines in [Using lower-case roman numerals in `enumerate` lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54055/5764) which shows ways to change the labelling using [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate), [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and no packages at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be easily done with `enumitem` and its `label` option. Since the letter P is to be followed by a arabic number, the label `P\arabic*` is used.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries P\arabic*}]
\item First
\item Second
\item Third
\item Fourth
\end{enumerate}

Let's play around: 

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries P\arabic*}]
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\end{enumerate}

Hold on for a while... and resume

\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\item \Ordinalstring{enumi}
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you load `enumitem` with `shortlabels` options, you can use `\begin{enumerate}[P1]` to get the enumeration you want.

Comment: @Manuel: (+1) Yes, I am aware of that, but I wanted to show a more general approach.