# Creating a myenumerate-environment with a counter

Tags: macros, itemize

I want to have the counter use roman numbers, so it should be something like:

(i) ...

(ii) ...

(iii) ...

I tried defining a macro \myitem, but it´s not really working. Does any have any ideas?

Comment: There are so many post on this that I won't provide an answer. But for your case, it is: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
 \item \dots
 \item \dots
 \item \dots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`

Comment: Another dupe: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54055