# Defining names for \item with the enumerate package

Tags: numbering, enumerate

For the code

```
\begin{myenumerate}
  \myitem A
  \myitem B
  \myitem C
```

I want the result to be

(i) A
(ii) B
(iii) C

How do I do that?

Comment: You should look at [Using lower-case roman numerals in enumerate lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54055/5764) (possible duplicate). With [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) all you need is `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]`... Are you fixed on the use of `myenumerate` and `\myitem`?

Comment: Yes, I am. I understand how to use the enumerate package if I just wanted \item, it´s the \myitem part that I have problems with.

Comment: I don't understand the usage of `\myitem` here? What's the point of it. It seems to be the same as `\item`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to define your `myenumerate`, and also set `\myitem` to be equivalent to `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
\let\myitem\item

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
  \myitem A
  \myitem B
  \myitem C
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you're not using the optional argument of `\item`, then there's no real need to use [`letltxmacro`](http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro).

Another option would be to define a "surrounding environment":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{myenumerate}
  {\let\myitem\item
   \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
  \myitem A
  \myitem B
  \myitem C
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

---

The following would be a way to achieve your output using [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\newenvironment{myenumerate}
  {\let\myitem\item
   \begin{enumerate}[(i)]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
  \myitem A
  \myitem B
  \myitem C
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That´s great, thank you! Is there a way to do this using just the enumerate package?

Comment: @TierraT: I've added an enumerate package option.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned @Werner, this you can accomplised with `emunitem` packages or with `paralist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{paralist}

        \begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item   A
    \item   B
    \item   C
    \end{enumerate}
        \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This uses `enumitem` and its ability to clone the usual `enumerate` lists with `\newlist` and define it as a maximum 2 level nesting list, with first level labelled lower case roman figures, the deeper level with upper case roman figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myromanumerate}{enumerate}{2}

\setlist[myromanumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}  % First level
\setlist[myromanumerate,2]{label=(\Roman*)}  % Second level
\begin{document}
\begin{myromanumerate}
\item   A
  \begin{myromanumerate}
  \item AA
  \item AB
  \end{myromanumerate}
\item   B
\item   C
\end{myromanumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]