# Itemize inside newenvironment

Tags: environments, itemize

I am new at LaTeX. My question is why this code doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage} 

 \newcounter{const}
 \renewcommand{\theconst}{\roman{const}}

 \renewcommand{\item}{\stepcounter{const} (\theconst)}
 \newcommand{\myitem}{\item}

\newenvironment{myenumerate}
{ \begin{itemize} }
{ \end{itemize} }

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
   \myitem A
   \myitem B
   \myitem C
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you just interested in a list that prints its items using (i), (ii), (iii), ...? Should it look like a regular list?

Comment: you have redefined `\item` are you sure you want to redefine that? this is used in the following environments none of which would work now, enumerate, itemize, description, verbatim, center, quote, ...

Comment: Probably the answer to this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54055/101651 could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `\item` does more than just print the items within the list. Specifically, it sets a flag to identify that you've provided at least one `\item` within any list (amongst other things). Redefining `\item` in the way you did removes this functionality and therefore throws an error under the regular list environment (`myenumerate` in your example emulates a regular `enumerate` list).

If all you're after is an enumerated list using `\roman` numbers, then you can use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label = (\roman*)}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenumerate}
 \myitem A
 \myitem B
 \myitem C
\end{myenumerate}

\end{document}
```

This can also be changed to print an inline list, as well as a host of other modifications.