# How to enumerate with small roman capitals (not lowercases)?

Tags: enumerate

Although I have seen many similar questions, none has been useful.

The question is quite simple: How do I reproduce the highlighted numerals in the image below?

[image: Little roman numerals.]

Note that the form of the numerals addressed in questions as [Using lower-case roman numerals in enumerate lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54055/using-lower-case-roman-numerals-in-enumerate-lists) is different from this one.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The question linked does not address the specific question I am asking. Pay attention to the form of the numerals. They are not the same.

Comment: Did you find that question in your search? If so, did you try to use lowercase `\roman` numerals with `\scshape`? Formatting of the enumeration display is a very general question and you can change it to your liking, either by reducing the font size of `\Roman`, or using `s`mall`c`aps with `\roman`. It doesn't really deserve a question for each possible formatting requirement.

Comment: Although you may say that, it cannot be inferred from the linked question (that I did see) that you can use such a thing as `\scshape` to format the numerals, which is why I asked this question. Your answer below is not included in any other question that I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\scriptsize\Roman*)}]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\scshape\roman*)}]
  \item One
  \item Two
  \item Three
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```