# What's the difference between the enumerate and enumitem packages?

Tags: packages, enumerate, enumitem

Is there an advantage to using the enumerate package over the enumitem package or vice versa? I use enumitem and my co-worker uses enumerate, and we're trying to decide which should be used when we collaborate.

Answer (score 81):

use `enumitem` (I wrote `enumerate`)

Comment: @Tvde1 well enumitem has a full enumerate emulation so it does everything enumerate does plus a lot more and has the benefit of nearly 30 years  of tex development, the basic code of enumerate hasn't changed since 1991.

Comment: This is most likely the most useful not-the-answer-to-the-question post I've seen so far.

Answer (score 33):

The [`enumitem` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) is far more flexible when compared with [`enumerate`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumerate). The latter provides an optional argument where you can specify the item number format using a generic representation while the former provides a key-value interface where one can specify number format representation in addition to a host of other list-related settings (or perform these settings globally). Here are two examples:

- Parenthesized lowercase roman numerals:

  ```
    % enumerate interface
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
      % Your list here
    \end{enumerate}

    % enumitem interface
    \begin{enumerate}[label = (\roman*)]
      % Your list here
    \end{enumerate}
  ```
- Bracketed uppercase alphabetic characters

  ```
    % enumerate interface
    \begin{enumerate}[{[A]}]
      % Your list here
    \end{enumerate}

    % enumitem interface
    \begin{enumerate}[label = {[\Alph*]}]
      % Your list here
    \end{enumerate}
  ```

The interface provided by `enumitem` is more intuitive and verbose (you specify `label` explicitly, including the counter representation format `\Alph` rather than `A`). Additionally, `enumitem` provides a host of other options, including

- separate `label` and `ref` keys for alternative references to labels,
- spacing adjustments (vertical and horizontal),
- in-line list enumeration,
- list continuation,
- new list style generation,
- ...

In short, `enumitem` provides a modern, user-friendly, key-value interface to many list manipulations, while `enumerate` is only geared towards short-hand list representation.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the `shortlabels` option `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` allows you to use the same syntax as the `enumerate` package, which makes its use much less verbose and much more pleasant.