# A fancy and beautiful type of enumerate in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, enumerate

I'm trying to reproduce the enumerate enviorment of this post ([A fancy and beautiful type of enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430542/a-fancy-and-beautiful-type-of-enumerate)) in **Beamer**. My MWE, adapted from there, is the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Colorlist}{red,blue,green,yellow}
\newcommand{\SebastianoItem}[1]{\foreach \X[count=\Y] in \Colorlist
{\ifnum\Y=#1\relax
\xdef\SebastianoColor{\X}
\fi
}
\tikz[baseline=(SebastianoItem.base),remember
picture]{%
\node[fill=\SebastianoColor,inner sep=4pt,font=\sffamily,fill opacity=0.5] (SebastianoItem){#1)};}
}
\newcommand{\SebastianoHighlight}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\fill[\SebastianoColor,fill opacity=0.5] ([yshift=4pt,xshift=-\pgflinewidth]SebastianoItem.east) -- ++(4pt,-4pt)
-- ++(-4pt,-4pt) -- cycle;
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\SebastianoItem{\arabic{enumi}}}

Some general advices.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item No fast food.
    \item Don't drink to much alcohol.
    \item No pineapple on pizza. \SebastianoHighlight
    \item Don't use onions in food.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I uncomment the \renewcommand and the \SebastianoHighlight lines, the code compiles, so I guess the errors are there. I know that renewing commands in Beamer are trickier than in the Article documentclass. However, I can't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Half of the problem is the Beamer does enumerate differently, and to customize the labels you should use a different command. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7513/119 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In beamer:**

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\SebastianoItem{\arabic{enumi}}}
```

Similarly for **enumerate subitem**, **enumerate subsubitem**, and enumerate mini template.

**edit file:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Colorlist}{red,blue,green,yellow}
\newcommand{\SebastianoItem}[1]{\foreach \X[count=\Y] in \Colorlist
{\ifnum\Y=#1\relax
\xdef\SebastianoColor{\X}
\fi
}
\tikz[baseline=(SebastianoItem.base),remember
picture]{%
\node[fill=\SebastianoColor,inner sep=4pt,font=\sffamily,fill opacity=0.5] (SebastianoItem){#1)};}
}
\newcommand{\SebastianoHighlight}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\fill[\SebastianoColor,fill opacity=0.5] ([yshift=4pt,xshift=-\pgflinewidth]SebastianoItem.east) -- ++(4pt,-4pt)
-- ++(-4pt,-4pt) -- cycle;
}}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\SebastianoItem{\arabic{enumi}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\SebastianoItem{\arabic{enumi}}}

Some general advices.
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item No fast food.
    \item Don't drink to much alcohol.
    \item No pineapple on pizza. \SebastianoHighlight
    \item Don't use onions in food.
  \end{enumerate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Comment: -1 copied from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430542/a-fancy-and-beautiful-type-of-enumerate/430550#430550

Comment: I just edited @avemaria file.